# symfony2 custom entity to array function

Tags: arrays, symfony, entity

I have to help me convert an entity to array but I have issues resolving associated records, which I need.

However, this gives me an error

> The class 'Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection' was not found in the
>   chain configured namespaces ...

The code follows:

```
public function serialize($entityObject)
{
$data = array();

$className = get_class($entityObject);
$metaData = $this->entityManager->getClassMetadata($className);

foreach ($metaData->fieldMappings as $field => $mapping)
{
    $method = "get" . ucfirst($field);
    $data[$field] = call_user_func(array($entityObject, $method));
}

foreach ($metaData->associationMappings as $field => $mapping)
{

    // Sort of entity object
    $object = $metaData->reflFields[$field]->getValue($entityObject);

        if ($object instanceof ArrayCollection) {
            $object = $object->toArray();
        }
        else {
            $data[$field] = $this->serialize($object);
        }

}

return $data;
}
```

How can I resolve the associated fields into their respective arrays.

I have tried using the built-in, and JMS serialiser, but this gives me issues of nestedness limits, so this is not an option for me.

UPDATE:
I have updated the code to handle instance of ArrayCollection as per @ScayTrase's suggestion. However, the error above is still reported with a one-to-many field map. In debug, the variable $object is of type "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection"

Answer (score 1):

For `*toMany` association properties implemented with `ArrayCollection` you should call `ArrayCollection::toArray()` first. Just check it with `instanceof` before, like this

```
if ($object instanceof ArrayCollection) {
    $object = $object->toArray();
}
```

Comment: That worked. I also had to add a check  for PersistentCollection"if ($object instanceof PersistentCollection) { $data[$field] = $object->toArray(); }"

Comment: @crafter I think it would better to check if for `Collection` interface to be sure. Documentations examples `ArrayCollection` usage, but I think any `Collection` suits, so check the interface instead.